# Making a USB2 GPS dongle work on USB3

Tags: windows-10, usb, drivers

I have bought a Gigabyte Brix BACE 3150 to use as a computer on a yacht.  It will not run my USB2 GPS, which is a U-blox 7 device.  The Gigabyte quick start guide says that due to lack of legacy EHCI controller support on 5th & 6th generation Intel CPU the USB3 ports on the Brix are not compatible with USB2 devices.  I would not have bought it if I had known that!  Gigabyte provide a driverCD that contains tools called "Windows 7 install utility/GbtUSBmaker.exe"  This is intended to make the USB3 ports compatible with USB2 devices.  It is only provided to install Windows 7, and I have already installed Windows 10.  In any case the CD appears to be corrupted as neither my main desktop, nor a laptop can transfer the files from it to a USB3 memory stick as it requires.

Is there any utility I can download that will install legacy support so that the USB3 ports can operate the USB2 GPS?

Comment: You are asking an off-topic question (software shopping). Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic. See [On Topic](http://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/  but please first read [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information).

Comment: You could try using a USB2 hub plugged into your USB3 port?

Comment: @BigChris That wouldn't work. The USB2 hub still needs a USB2 port on the computer. USB2 and USB3 are completely different hardware technologies that happen to share the same connector/cables.  Any device/hub that supports both internally has 2 separate interfaces for the 2 types of ports. USB2 devices talk USB2, USB3 devices talk USB3. You can't convert internally between the 2 inside the hub. A hub can't magically convert USB2 signals into USB3.

Comment: @DavidPostill In my view this question is about troubleshooting a driver/hardware issue. It is NOT software shopping in the normal sense even though the user literally asks for software advise. I wouldn't close it for that.

Comment: If it's a driver issue, you could use the website driverscloud.com to find the drivvers you need. I used it several times and it litterally saved my life.

Comment: You can download the Windows USB Installation Tool [here](http://www.gigabyte.com/products/product-page.aspx?pid=5568#utility). Whether it will work with Windows 10 is another question ...

Comment: @Tonny USB is (normally) forwards and backwards compatible ...

Comment: @DavidPostill That is widely held misconception. It only applies to USB1.0 1.1 and 2.0. NOT to USB3/3.1.  I had reason to study the entire USB 3 specification. All 5000 pages of it. What goes on in the hardware/lowlevel software is really messy.

Comment: @Tonny Please explain why my USB 3.0 devices work in a USB 2.0 port and vice versa? Note I'm talking devices and ports **not** controllers.

Comment: My main reasoning for using, say, a USB hub, is the same as this question and working answer: http://superuser.com/questions/800743/mac-air-bootcamp-windows-7-installation-and-usb3-hurdles - obviously it's different machines/problem but the USB portion is exactly what I was referring to...? I know nothing about USB 3 but I would have thought the backward/forward compatibility would ensure all 1.1 -> 3.1 would at least "work" (not necessarily at the fastest speeds the later devices are capable of)...?

Answer (score 1):

You are sheer out of luck.

The USB ports on this NUC are strictly USB3 only. There is no way you can run a USB2 device from these ports. It is a hardware issue. Software/drivers can't fix this.

(The utility you mention does something else: It modifies a Windows 7 installation image to include the USB3 drivers that are normally not present in Windows 7. This allows you to use a USB3 memory stick as installation media on this NUC.)

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :
I am beginning to think that this is actually a problem with the dongle itself.  Gigabyte replied to me with a link to a BIOS version update and I flashed the BIOS to version 3.  After that the dongle still did not get a fix, so I again tried it on a laptop where it had previously worked very well.  This time it took longer to get a fix but did still work.  I tried to apply a firmware update, but that failed.  I have now ordered a new and different GPS dongle to see if will work with the Brix.  I do not believe it is a driver issue as both the Brix and the Windows 10 laptop on which the dongle works show exactly the same driver files.
Separately I tested the BRIX by plugging in an old USB2 Seagate hard drive, and was able to see it as drives D & E, and copy files from it, so I have to conclude that the USB3 system on the Brix is compatible with most USB2 devices, including the wireless mouse and keyboard, but has a compatibility issue with the U-blox 7 GPS dongle, for which there may be no solution as the attempt to update the U-blox firmware failed.